# Kafka / Mock topic for easy consumer development

Tags: apache-kafka, node-kafka

Given that the entire kafka pipeline is quite heavy,
and demands quite a lots of resources.

I'd like to mock a topic,
so that I could test and develop the consumer independently/separately.

I couldn't really find too much,
I am also new to Kafka.

I imagine we could have something like:

```sh
docker run fake-topic -v stubs:/messages -it localhost:12345
```

and then,
later in the consumer code:

```
import { ConsumerGlobalConfig, ConsumerTopicConfig } from 'node-rdkafka';

const consumer: Kafka.KafkaConsumer = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer({
  'metadata.broker.list': 'localhost:12345',
}, topicConfig);
```

So that our fake would dispatch something hardcoded in `stubs/*.txt`

Comment: Have you tried using Testcontainers project?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Docker configuration for quite lightweight self-contained Kafka. You can build an image from it and run and restart it easily: https://github.com/up9inc/async-ms-demo/tree/main/kafka

In addition, you could find useful the Mockintosh project features around Kafka: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x2rLFMdiOI

Comment: Disclaimer: I am affiliated with Mockintosh project

Comment: I have built this too https://github.com/hitmands/kafka-producer-stub

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [Specmatic Kafka Mock](https://specmatic.in/updates/kafka-mocking-with-asyncapi-using-specmatic/). Here is a [node sample project](https://github.com/znsio/specmatic-order-bff-nodejs). You can leverage Kafka mock both in your tests or as a standalone mock server to aid your development.

Instead of having to setup topics through command line, you can specify the same with [AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/) specification and Specmatic will start a broker, setup your topic and also validate the messages that arrive on that topic as per the schema in your AsyncAPI specification.

Disclosure: I am co-founder and CTO at [Specmatic](https://specmatic.in/)